# iOS12 Messages stopped previewing links

Tags: ios, hyperlink, sms, imessage

For some reason link previews on SMSs on Messages (and I'm guessing iMessage as well) stopped working after upgrading to iOS 12.

The previous behavior was to ensure that the link was included at the end of the SMS and ensure target page had the necessary meta tags.

Did Apple changed the requirements?